# Action not occurring on AM/PM time

Tags: c#, string, datetime

my app checks the `DateTime.Now` from combobox's selected by the user. My issue is, I have tried added to check if it's AM or PM via

`if (DateTime.Now.Hour == tbox1 && DateTime.Now.Minute == tbox2 && DateTime.Now.ToString("tt") == comboBox5.Text)`

(`comboBox5` can only be `AM` or `PM`) however nothing is occurring.

This is all in local time to make it more user friendly for the user.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int tbox1 = int.Parse(comboBox1.Text);
    int tbox2 = int.Parse(comboBox2.Text);
    int tbox3 = int.Parse(comboBox3.Text);
    int tbox4 = int.Parse(comboBox4.Text);

    if (DateTime.Now.Hour == tbox1 
        && DateTime.Now.Minute == tbox2 
        && DateTime.Now.ToString("tt") == comboBox5.Text)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(textBox1.Text);
        form2.Show();
        simpleSound.Play();
    }           

    if (DateTime.Now.Hour == tbox3 
        && DateTime.Now.Minute == tbox4 
        && DateTime.Now.ToString("tt") == comboBox6.Text)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(textBox2.Text);
        form2.Show();
        simpleSound.Play();
    }
}
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using breakpoints to verify that the `tbox` values are what you think they are?  Do you actually get inside the `if` statements?

Comment: Yes. The ones for hours are limited to 1-12, and minutes 1-60.

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: For me, it's `en-US`

Comment: `The ones for hours are limited to 1-12, and minutes 1-60.` Not according to `DateTime.Hour`, valid values are 0-23.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "nothing is occurring"?  The new form isn't being created?  The new form isn't being shown?  The `simpleSound` isn't playing?

Comment: @Michael McGriff, none of that occurs. The program just continues on.

Comment: `DateTime.Hour` can have values from `0` to `23` and `DateTime.Minute` can have values from `0` to `59`. Are you sure your comboboxes provider these values correctly? Debug your code and tell us.

Comment: @Caramiriel So how would I go about using 1-12 and AM/PM checks? Something other than `DateTime.Hour`?

Comment: You should lookup the docs on date time to see how to use the API. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Comment: @Soner Gönül using 0-23 defeats my purpose of checking for AM/PM. Debugger shows no errors. Yes, if I enter 13 for hour and 5 for minute, it will work at 1:05 PM, but I want to avoid using anything greater than 12.

Comment: `if (amPmComboBox.Text == "PM") { hours += 12 }`? And why do you want to reinvent the wheel? What are you going to do if your timer misses a second? What if the application isn't running at the configured time?

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.Now.Hour` [per the API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.hour.aspx), returns "The hour component, expressed as a value between 0 and 23."

If you want it expressed as a # between 1-12, you must use ToString and specify the format.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("%h");
```

will return the hour between 1-12.

Comment: Sorry, but where exactly would I be putting this?

Comment: Wherever you have 'DateTime.Now.Hour  == tbox1'.  Right now, I'm guessing it's 8:22pm where you are.  Which DateTime.Now.Hour returns as 20.   You want it to return 8. 'DateTime.Now.ToString("%h");' will return 8.